# Adding rows and columns to HTML with jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my html code:

```
<h3>Ilm selles linnas</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>city_id</th>
        <th>temp</th>
        <th>date</th>
    </tr>
    <div id="info"></div>
</table>
```

this is my script:

```
function(data) {
            $('#info').empty();
            var html = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                html += "<tr>"+
                    "<td>"+data[i].id+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+data[i].city_id+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+data[i].temperature+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+data[i].date+"</td>"+
                "</tr>";                
            }
            $('#info').append(html);
}
```

After this is done, in the real ouput this happens:

[image]

So:

**1) All the info is higher than table headers (`<th>` tag)**

**2) All the info isn't in the column, but just smashed together**

**3) None of the info is showed in HTML source.**

What must I change to make it look as it should?

Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Can't have a div in the middle of a table like that; append to the table. And it won't be in the HTML source, because it's not on the HTML source--you need to inspect the elements to get the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove your `<div id="info"></div>` and append directly to the table.

```
$('table tr:gt(0)').remove();

var html = "";
$(data).each(function() {
    html += "<tr>"+
                "<td>"+this.id+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+this.city_id+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+this.temperature+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+this.date+"</td>"+
            "</tr>";    
});   

$('table').append(html);
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Xdbqs/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a div in a table.  Try this:

```
<table id="datatable">
<tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>city_id</th>
    <th>temp</th>
    <th>date</th>
</tr>
</table>

function(data) {
        var html = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            html += "<tr>"+
                "<td>"+data[i].id+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[i].city_id+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[i].temperature+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+data[i].date+"</td>"+
            "</tr>";                
        }
        $('#datatable').append(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="info">
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>city_id</th>
        <th>temp</th>
        <th>date</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As stated it's your markup.  Change it to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a div. You could just use a  and your code would work.